# Bluetooth earbuds touch gestures should trigger onClick listener in the app

Tags: android, bluetooth, touch, gesture, android-bluetooth

I am trying to make an android app which triggers an on click listener/some action in the app when any touch gesture has been performed on the paired Bluetooth earbuds (earbuds support touch gestures). Googled quite a lot but still unable to make it work. Based on the received intent's action would want to figure out what the gesture was and then trigger some action in my app accordingly. Could anyone please guide me or point me towards the right approach? Thanks in advance.

My device is android 9, api level 28. Want to make it work for android devices with version >= 8.

Tried out the following:

1. Registered a listener and set the priority of intent filter to 2147483647 but unable to receive broadcasts in onReceive method.
2. Tried capturing keyevents in onKeyDown/onKeyUp/dispatchKeyEvent but not receiving calls in these methods.
3. Tried using Media Session class and setting the callback and the playback state and setting it to Active but did not receive call in onMediaButtonEvent or any of the overridden methods of the callback.

1st approach:

AndroidManifest.xml

Inside application tag:

```
<receiver android:name="MediaButtonBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
 <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Outside application tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

MainActivity.java in onCreate()

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
ComponentName mReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(this, MediaButtonBroadcastReceiver.class);
mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent)
```

MediaButtonBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class MediaButtonBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Constructor is mandatory
    public MediaButtonBroadcastReceiver ()
    {
        super ();
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Hello2 ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

2nd approach:
Added these in MainActivity.java's onCreate() -

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Hello1 ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {\
        Toast.makeText(this,"Hello3 ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Hello4 ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {\
        Toast.makeText(this,"Hello5 ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

3rd approach -

```
MediaSession.Callback callback = new MediaSession.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(final Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
                Log.e("KISHIE", "HELLO");
                Toast toast= Toast. makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello ",Toast. LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setMargin(50,50);
                toast.show();
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPlay() {
                Log.e("KISHIE", "HELLO");
            }
            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                Log.e("KISHIE", "HELLO");
            }
            @Override
            public void onSkipToNext() {
                Log.e("KISHIE", "HELLO");
            }
            @Override
            public void onSkipToPrevious() {
                Log.e("KISHIE", "HELLO");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFastForward() {
                Log.e("KISHIE", "HELLO");
            }
            @Override
            public void onRewind() {
                Log.e("KISHIE", "HELLO");
            }
            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                Log.e("KISHIE", "HELLO");
            }
        };

        MediaSession mediaSession = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(),"KISHIE"); // Debugging tag, any string
        mediaSession.setFlags( MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mediaSession.setCallback(callback);

        // Set up what actions you support and the state of your player
        PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder()
                .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)
                .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 0, 0)
                .build();
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(state);
        // Call this when you start playback after receiving audio focus
        mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

Comment: Good question but might be hard to answer. Some potential guiding questions: The 214... magic number, where did it come from? Is it possible that the problem is hardware/earbud specific (i.e. have you googled this problem *with your earbud model* included in the search query)? Also might be good nice to edit your question and add some minimal code and/or links to what/how you've tried (in addition to the verbal descriptions you gave above).

Comment: @EmilVatai thanks for the suggestion, I have added code snippets. This 2147483647 number I used randomly to assign a high priority to the intent filter to make sure the gestures are received in this test app and are not going to any other app.
And I have tried out with 2 different bluetooth earphones and didn't work with either, so it shouldn't be device specific.

Comment: Googled "android earbuds API" and found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset). Do you see something which might be of interest? (Sorry didn't read it myself)

Comment: And from that page got to [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/profiles) somehow, which sees like a good starting point... (thanks = upvote in this neck of the woods :) )